# Flutter TextInputFormatter not allowing RegEx

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want my TextFormField to accept a string like `ABCDE1234F`. I tested the regex online and it works. For some reason, the FextFormField doesn't allow any kind of input when I use the following code.

```dart
TextFormField(
    inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}')),
    ],
    validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        labelText: 'PAN Number',
    ),
)
```

A valid string should have 5 uppercase letters, followed by 4 digits and a last uppercase letter.

Edit:
Playing around more with it, I realized that the issue is in `{}`. When I just allow digits or numbers without limiting the number with `{}`, it works. But I can't limit seem to limit number of characters.

Comment: In your case, when you tap `A`, which can't pass your `[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}`. So in Sam's answer,`([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$)|([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{1,4}$)|[A-Z]{1,5}$`, `A` can pass `[A-Z]{1,5}`, and `ABCDE1` can pass `([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{1,4}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern should be

```
RegExp(r'([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$)|([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{1,4}$)|[A-Z]{1,5}$')
```

and

```
validator: (value) {
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$');
if (value.isEmpty) {
     return 'Please enter some text';
}else if (regExp.hasMatch(value)){
     return "input more."
}
     return null;
},
```

Comment: Tried all three options. Still not working.

Comment: @NasumTapil I change something, you can try it again

Comment: Hey. Thanks for that. But RegExp.allMatches(value) isn't a Boolean value.

Comment: @NasumTapil my bad, you should use `hasMatch`, not `allMatches`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below as your input formater:

```
inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                      RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9]"),
                    ),
                  ]
```

Hope this will work for you !!

Comment: This would work but my issue is I want to limit the number of characters. Like I said in the question, 5 of [A-Z], 4 digits and 1 [A-Z] again. When I use the {5} to limit, the TextFormField does not allow any input.