# How to check is the text is in right format? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a condition as the particular text must be in the particular format where in I'm getting the text from the scanner and need to check if it is in the right format.

The format comes like
**The starting letter must start with `e or E`, next letter might be any letter from `a to z or A to Z` alphabets, next 9 characteres must be `numbers` and the last two characters must be from anything within `a to z or A to Z` alphabets**

I tried something like

`if (_scannedCode.startsWith('e|E') && _scannedCode[1].startsWith('a-zA-Z') && _scannedCode.substring(2, 10))`
but got struck.

---

Seeing the answers did get the condtions correctly but was struck up with one, so just wanted to get a clarification if its right or not

```
RegExp emo = new RegExp(r'[0-9]{6}(EM|em|eM|Em){2}[0-9]{10}$');
```

As i needed the first 6 characters to be numbers the next two characters be alphabet(em) and the remaining 10 characters be numbers.

Comment: check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058512/flutter-textinputformatter-not-allowing-regex/66058876](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058512/flutter-textinputformatter-not-allowing-regex/66058876)

Comment: You can use regex: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final regex = RegExp(r'(e|E)[a-zA-z]\d{9}[a-zA-z]{2}');
if (_scannedCode.length == 13 && regex.hasMatch(_scannedCode) ) {
  // your code
}
```